# Why does sqoop map DECIMAL types in an import from Teradata to DOUBLE?

Tags: hadoop, hive, teradata, sqoop

I've got Sqoop version: 1.4.6

When importing data from Teradata into Hive, I find that DECIMAL types are converted to DOUBLE.

I wonder why that is when Hive has an exact equivalent datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because they wrote it generically for all the RDBMS.

`DECIMAL` is mapped with `DOUBLE`.

Useful part of [source code](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/hive/HiveTypes.java#L39):

```
 public static String toHiveType(int sqlType) {

      switch (sqlType) {
          case Types.INTEGER:
          case Types.SMALLINT:
              return "INT";
          case Types.VARCHAR:
          case Types.CHAR:
          case Types.LONGVARCHAR:
          case Types.NVARCHAR:
          case Types.NCHAR:
          case Types.LONGNVARCHAR:
          case Types.DATE:
          case Types.TIME:
          case Types.TIMESTAMP:
          case Types.CLOB:
              return "STRING";
          case Types.NUMERIC:
          case Types.DECIMAL:
          case Types.FLOAT:
          case Types.DOUBLE:
          case Types.REAL:
              return "DOUBLE";
          case Types.BIT:
          case Types.BOOLEAN:
              return "BOOLEAN";
          case Types.TINYINT:
              return "TINYINT";
          case Types.BIGINT:
              return "BIGINT";
          default:
        // TODO(aaron): Support BINARY, VARBINARY, LONGVARBINARY, DISTINCT,
        // BLOB, ARRAY, STRUCT, REF, JAVA_OBJECT.
        return null;
      }
  }
```

They also put warning for this mapping for DATE, TIME, TIMESTAMP, DECIMAL, NUMERIC SQL data types.

```
  if (HiveTypes.isHiveTypeImprovised(colType)) {
    LOG.warn(
        "Column " + col + " had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive");
  }
```

Check [source code](https://github.com/apache/sqoop/blob/7c1754270ff21f533088b946c873321f890da791/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/hive/TableDefWriter.java#L187) for details.

Comment: be nice if they could fix that.

Comment: @user55570 they wrote basic mapping as they can not test each and every data type for all the RDBMS. That's why we have `map-column-hive` tag

Comment: Yes, understand. Maybe an option for a type mapping of a source data type would be good rather than having to enumerate the correction for every field name. And of course double is a poor translation of a DECIMAL type, which can be whole number type, so it would be good to be able to somehow address.

Comment: @user55570 yes agree with you, there is a room for improvement...:)